# SELECT COUNT(`id`)FROM `table` WHERE merk LIKE '%$searchq%'

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to count how many results I get when i use my search engine..

Here is my html code:

```
<form id="header-search" action="car-list.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search"  id="text" placeholder="Zoek hier.."   class="quick-search"  > </form>
```

Php code:

```
     $searchq = $_GET['search'];
     $searchq = str_replace(' ','-',$searchq);     
    $con =  mysql_connect("localhost","root","****");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("register-login", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`car_id`)FROM `adver` WHERE merk LIKE '%$searchq%' OR titel LIKE '%$searchq%' OR model LIKE '%$searchq%'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];



$pages = new Paginator;  
$pages->items_total = $total;
$pages->mid_range = 5;  
$pages->paginate();
```

Im doing this to know "$pages->items_total = $total;" for my pagination.

Code for display results:

```
$searchq = htmlspecialchars($searchq); 
$searchq = mysql_real_escape_string($searchq);                  
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adver` WHERE merk LIKE '%$searchq%' OR titel LIKE '%$searchq%' OR model LIKE '%$searchq%' ORDER BY car_id DESC $pages->limit")or die(mysql_error());

while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_array($photo)){ 


?>


                                        <a href="<?php echo 'car-details.php?merk='.$get_photo['merk'] .'&car_id=' .$get_photo['car_id'] .'&titel=' .$get_photo['titel'] ;?>">
                            <img src="<?php  echo $get_photo['path'] ; ?>" style="border:1px solid #021a40;" alt="<?php  echo $get_photo['merk'] ;?>" }/>
```

Everyyhing is working fine until, when I search for something that doesn't exist in my databse. So $result =  0. Then I get the fowllowing error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10,10' at line 1

When I change my $result = mysql_query to ==> ("SELECT COUNT(`car_id`)FROM `adver`");
Then everything works fine exept my pagination numbers... Because I count every car_id, no matter what I'm searching.. I'm getting for exampple 3 empty pages..

I hope someone can help me with this problem,Thanks

Comment: One addition tipp: Use mysqli instead of mysql functions and read a bit about prepared statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is always a pain with LIMITS, it seems that you specify a limit of -10,10 (so a negative start); probably in `$pages->limit`, this seems to be the issue.

Is there any performance consideration in not using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`? With that you can get the total count of results, regardless of using a LIMIT clause.

Comment: I should take a look at $pages->limit, the problem should be somewhere around there!Thanks! Let you know if i found something

Comment: Hi, The problem was as you said the $pages->limit.
I have created a simpel if statement to check if I have a zero result.

Something like this:

if ($total > 0)
{   
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `adver` WHERE merk LIKE '%$searchq%' OR titel LIKE '%$searchq%' OR model LIKE '%$searchq%' ORDER BY car_id DESC $pages->limit")or die(mysql_error());

 if(mysql_num_rows($photo) > 0)
  {

while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_assoc($photo)){
{
// my loop
}
}
else {
echo ("No Records Found");
} !

Answer (score 1):

You will get an alias of **COUNT(*)** and take this field after:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `adver` WHERE merk LIKE '%$searchq%' OR title LIKE '%$searchq%' OR model LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row['total']; //use alias
```

You have wrong field name (i think): **titel** will be **title**

To debug your query, you will add **or die(mysql_error())** after your **mysql_query** call (see my code)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for youre respose, but I'm still getting the same error.
BTW the field name is 'titel'(Is in Dutch)

Comment: Can you try removing the AS keyword between COUNT(*) and total

Comment: What is your exactly table name and column names?

Comment: Table name = adver and column names are : model,titel,merk